# Front end for an iOS web app using Django Rest API

Tags: html, ios, django, rest, frontend

I ve recently been asked to work in the front-end of a new app which will be written with Django for back end.(They said it will be for iOS).
Even though I have experience working with front-end I never wrote any code for iOS or Django REST API. What are the differences? Is it html/css ?

In another words lets assume that someone has a code in Django which asks user a question and stores the answer. The response will be in JSON(I think.) He wants me to write front end. Should I write it in html?

One more question: What will determine that our app will be working in iOS and will not work in android. They said the app will be for iOS at first but since it uses REST API what is the reason it cannot be available at the same time for android?

Answer (score 0):

The usual process of using django rest framework is to have interactions with your backend exclusively using json.(most of the time, some people might use xml). So in general, all the information (requests and responses) will be JSON. Once you have that part setup, there are a number of technologies that will help you create user interfaces. You can use angularjs or JQuery to send JSON requests and responses to the endpoints and display the information obtained.(the whole interface is modified with javascript.)

Now, for your mobile apps. There are two approaches you either create what people call a native app using Java(for android apps) or Swift(for apple devices).
If you decide to use that approach you will have to mantain both apps in different languages. The other way of doing things would be to create an interface using something like angularjs and use a tool like ionic to convert that app into an android/apple app. Using that approach you will only have to mantain 1 application.

Here is a small diagram to represent the interaction.

(Django rest framework) <=JSON=> (front end app.)

I would suggest to start with django templates, it might just do the trick.

Comment: Thats what I plan to do. I already have experience writing android apps in Java when I was a student in college. According to your response once the code is written with Django Rest framework using JSON request and response the website application will be available at the same time for both android and iOS right?

Comment: That's correct. Both can interpret JSON objects using json parsers(for instance okhttp for android, java.)

Comment: You'll need to check django-oauth2-provider for authentication 2, when doing calls to the api.